# Linux Eval and Cat to print output on multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my test code

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMPLATEEMAIL="/mydir/template.txt"
HELLOPRINT=`cat hello.txt`
emailbody=$(cat ${TEMPLATEEMAIL} | while read line; do eval echo "${line}"; done)
echo ${emailbody}

cat /mydir/template.txt
$HELLOPRINT

cat hello.txt
hello
hello
hello 
hello
```

---

Output I am intending to get is:

```
hello
hello 
hello 
hello
```

However output I am currently getting is:

```
hello hello hello hello
```

Comment: Format your code properly. It's unreadable now.

Comment: Learn to check you code first by copy/paste into https://shellcheck.net and fixing any flagged items. If you still have a problem, post the corrected code with a note "shellcheck verified". Good luck.

Comment: Totally agree with the 2 comments above. echo "$HELLOPRINT" will not interpret \n by default, if you want to echo interpreting the escape sequences (each hello on new line) you can use ```echo -e "$HELLOPRINT"```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. From what you say: You do a `hello.txt`, but the output you see is different from the output you expect. However, I don't see how you create the file hello.txt, so your question is meaningless - at least to me.

Comment: thanks for others for your valuable feedback, I written something different but somehow post turned out like this. I work in a place where the actual code cannot be shared. I tried the test program before sharing here. First part is the code, cat /mydir/template.txt onwards are the other file content called from the code. Basically question is i want the echo ${emailbody} to show "hello" in four lines instead of hello repeated 4 times in single line.

Comment: In order to keep the newlines, the argument of both `echo` commands must be quoted, i. e.  `eval echo \""${line}"\"` and `echo "${emailbody}"`.